# BigQuery Maximum name length

Tags: google-bigquery

What are the maximum lengths for identifiers in BigQuery (names for projects, data sets, tables, columns)?

The documentation just says "string" wherever these identifiers are referenced, but I can't find any indication of maximum sizes for these.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maximum length for table, dataset, and job ids are 1024 chars.
Maximum length for field names is 128 chars.
I don't know what the maximum length for a project name is, however.

Answer (score 1):

The new limits are

- table name - 1024
- column names - 300
- dataset name - 1,024
- Project id - 30
- project name - not found

These limits are not constant, so providing the links for future reference

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#dataset_limits